# intl's NumberFormat is giving 922,337,203,685,477,580,700 on very huge number

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using [intl](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/intl)'s [NumberFormat](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/intl/latest/intl/NumberFormat-class.html) class to format my numbers.

my pubspec.yaml is something like this:

```
intl:
```

I have this very huge number when a user type on the textfield:

```
1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
```

Without using intl, the output is this:

```
1e+21
```

And I wanted to format it so it could be readable by a normal human being.

So I did something like this:

```
NumberFormat myFormat = new NumberFormat("#,##0.00", "en_US");

...

String _input = _textController.text; // user's input

double _number = double.tryParse(_input);

String _formatted = '${myFormat.format(_number)}';
```

This worked on numbers lesser than 1e+21. However, when the user's input is equal to or greater than 1e+21, it gives a value of:

```
922,337,203,685,477,580,700.00   // output of 1e+21

922,337,203,685,477,580,700,000,000,000.00   // output of 1e+30
```

I am completely clueless why it gave a number like that.

I would appreciate any form of help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this flutter package [bignum](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bignum).